# How to access the returned json values

Tags: php, json

How can I access this variable in php ?

result->message->from->id

I decoded returned json with json_decode()
and I want to get value Through the above method

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "update_id": 176446579,
            "message": {
                "message_id": 7,
                "from": {
                    "id": 468822221,
                    "is_bot": false,
                    "first_name": "M.GH",
                    "last_name": "2003",
                    "username": "moji_2003",
                    "language_code": "fa"
                },
                "chat": {
                    "id": 468822221,
                    "first_name": "M.GH",
                    "last_name": "2003",
                    "username": "moji_2003",
                    "type": "private"
                },
                "date": 1550384619,
                "text": "salam"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it's all already clearly mentioned in [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$result` is an array, so you need to first access the first element in the array:

```
$json = json_decode('JSON_STRING');

$id = $json->result[0]->message->form->id;
```

Comment: According to [PHP's `json_decode` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), the function returns a `stdClass` instead of an array if the function's 2nd argument is not set to `true`. Nevertheless, it can still be used like an array.

Comment: An error occurs : 
Notice: Trying to get property 'result' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gptec-telebot\classes\robot.php on line 23
Notice: Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gptec-telebot\classes\robot.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to get property 'form' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gptec-telebot\classes\robot.php on line 23
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gptec-telebot\classes\robot.php on line 23

Comment: tnx probleme resolved

Comment: @YongQuan while true, if the generated object contains an array, it will still contain an array when decoded. Passing `true` to the second argument would mean we have to use: `$json['result'][0]['message']['form']['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access it this way:

```
 $data = json_decode($yourJsonString);
 echo $data->result[0]->message->from->id;
```